# Beautiful Soup: Get specific text that has no specific class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the highlighted text "frei ab 01.05.2017" below. The problem is however, that the class "section_content iw_right" exists 19 times on that website. I would do a find_all and return only the 11th element from there, however on some sites that I want to scrape there are a different number of that class, so I might not always catch the right one. Any ideas? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to post the url you are trying to scrape. Anyway, you should be able to find all `<string>` tags contained in `div`s that have this class.

Comment: Do all the other 18 `section_content iw_right` have the same child nodes? If not you could look for the one that has the Children you're looking for.

Comment: Can you post html text instead of an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get to the desired element is using the preceding label - locate the `span` element with "Erdgeschoss" text and [find the next `strong` sibling](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
label = soup.find("span", text="Erdgeschoss")
print(label.find_next_sibling("strong").get_text())
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! Is it bad practice to just do it in one line?

available = soup.find("span", text="Erdgeschoss").find_next_sibling("strong").get_text()

Comment: @user2252633 no problem, you can totally do that - just make sure it is still understandable and you handle possible errors - e.g. if `label` does not exist or if the `strong` element after does not..

Answer (score 1):

You can use **lxml** which is order of magnitude faster than **BeautifulSoup**.

The following code can help you in achieving the desired result.

```
from lxml import html
html_string = """
    <div class="clear">
        <div class="section_content iw_right">
            <p>
            <span>
            </span>
            <strong>hello</strong>
            <br>
            <strong>gen</strong>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear">
        <p>
        <span>
        </span>
        <strong>hello1</strong>
        <br>
        <strong>gen1</strong>
        </p>
    </div>
"""
root = html.fromstring(html_string)
r_xp = [elem.xpath('.//p/strong/text()')[0] for elem in root.xpath('//div[@class="clear"]')]
print(r_xp)
```

Note the absense of div with class `"section_content iw_right"` from second `div` in the example `html_string`.

The above code will result in :

```
['hello', 'hello1']
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Always good to learn something new!